# EOF not terminating when trying to count words in C

Tags: c, eof

I am reading K&R and one of the code counts words. I decided to try and make my own version of the code, but with my current code the EOF (`Ctrl+D` as I am on Linux) isn't working.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  int c, wc = 0;

  while((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
    while(c != ' ' && c != '\t' && c != '\n') {
      wc++;
    }
  }

  printf("%d", wc);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The inner loop is probably missing a getchar(). As it is, it never terminates. So what you should see is between 50% (old core i3) and 17% (Ryzen) CPU load because the program is busy incrementing wc (i.e. one true core resp. two hyperthreads at 100%).

Comment: Even with inner `getchar()` it wont count words. Possibly \w - chars, but not words

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider that works and grapes I fixed it to count words

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following example is a bit closer to counting **words**:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  int c, wc = 0;
  int sep = 1;
  while((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
    if (c != ' ' && c != '\t' && c != '\n') {
      if ( sep ){
        wc++;
        sep = 0;
      }
    }
    else
      sep = 1;
  }

  printf("%d", wc);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: what would sep stand for and how does it make it closer to counting words?

Comment: `sep` is a shorthand for `separator`. It means that now we are located in whitespace. Words counted only on transition from whitespace to \w-characters

Answer (score 1):

```
while((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
    while(c != ' ' && c != '\t' && c != '\n') {
      wc++;
    }
  }
```

When you press a key for first time, inner while loop triggers and never exits unless first key is one of those in the condition.

So if you press 'A', inner while loop goes on forever.

You need to replace `while` by `if`. And modify condition in a way where `wc` will increment only when it encounters  or other specified character and `getchar()` will be executed to fetch next character.

Comment: `if` won't really make the program correct, because then it will increment `wc` (presumably the word count) for every character that is not `' '`, `'\t'`, or `'\n'`.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons Realized it when I read my answer, and then updated it.

Answer (score 0):

I had to add `getchar()` to the inner `while` loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  int c, wc = 0;

  while((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
    while((c = getchar()) != ' ' && c != '\t' && c != '\n');
    wc++;
  }

  printf("%d\n", wc);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Again wont work. You immediately overwrite first char, got in outer loop. So it will miss 1-char words

Comment: @grapes not to mention that the `getchar` in the embedded loop doesn't check for `EOF`

Comment: @ChristianGibbons, exactly

Answer (score -1):

I know that I'm cheating but this example shows how higher-level functions make programs clearer. `scanf`'s `%s` conversion does the word-splitting for us. The example uses the `*` assignment-suppression character which obviates the need to provide space for arbitrarily long words which we actually don't want to know.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int wordcount = 0;

int main(void) {

  while(scanf("%*s") != EOF) 
  {
    wordcount++;
  }
  printf("%d\n", wordcount);
  return 0;
}
```

If I had to roll it my own, I'd write subroutines. Look how clean the `main`  looks!

```
#include <stdio.h>

/** @return 1 if c is whitespace, else 0. */
static int isWhite(int c);

/** When this function returns, c is either EOF or non-whitespace.
    @return c
*/
static int readWhite();

/** When this function returns, c is either EOF or whitespace.
    @return c
*/
static int readWord();

int main(void) {

  int wordcount = 0;

  while(readWhite() != EOF)
  {
    wordcount++;
    readWord();
  }

  printf("%d\n", wordcount);
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////
static int isWhite(int c)
{ 
  return c == '\n' || c == '\t' || c == ' '; 
}
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////
static int readWord()
{
  int c;
  while((c = getchar()) != EOF && !isWhite(c))
  {
    ; // this statement intentionally left blank
  }
  return c;
}
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////
static int readWhite()
{
  int c;
  while((c = getchar()) != EOF && isWhite(c))
  {
    ; // this statement intentionally left blank
  }
  return c;
}
```